# Recursive query using two tables?

Tags: recursion, oracle11g

I have a tree structure that is defined across two tables that I need to use to work out, starting from the leaf object, the folder path in which the leaf object exists.

FOLDER_DETAILS contains the object and the folder details, FOLDER_HIERARCHY contains the folder and its parent folder association, if there is one.

Each leaf object could be 1 folder level deep, or it could be 100 folder levels deep.

At the moment, I'm using recursive C# code to perform a query-per-level, which feels expensive and is definitely time-consuming over my connection to the database. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this via a single recursive query?

Current method:

Because I start this process already knowing the leaf object, it is easy for me to get its OBJECT_ID and OWNER_ID values. The OWNER_ID value for the leaf object is the id of the leaf folder.

From there, the basic outline of the queries I execute are:

```
SELECT FD.FOLDER_NAME, FD.FOLDER_ID, FH.OWNER_ID 
FROM FOLDER_DETAILS FD 
     INNER JOIN FOLDER_HIERARCHY FH ON FD.FOLDER_ID = FH.ID
WHERE FD.OBJECT_ID = :object_id 
AND FH.OWNER_ID = :owner_id;
```

From each query I collect the "FOLDER_NAME" value as the folder name for that level, and the "FOLDER_ID" (becomes the OBJECT_ID) and "OWNER_ID" are fed into the next iteration of the recursion.

Do this enough times, and I get a path made up of each of the folder names, from the leaf object back to the root folder.

But again, I would love to do this recursively in a single query...

Comment: Try using a [hierarchical (aka "connect by") query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm)

Comment: Thanks @TonyAndrews, the link you provided helped me close the gap on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link provided by @TonyAndrews was the solution. [hierarchical (aka "connected by") query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm)